# How can I create a dialogue system

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class NPCscript : Interactable {
    public GameObject dialougeObj;
    public TMP_Text dialouge;
    public int Size;
    public string dialougeSt;

    public override void Interact () {
        base.Interact ();
        dialougeObj.SetActive (true);
        NPCInteraction();
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        dialougeObj.SetActive(false);
    }
    void NPCInteraction(){
        dialouge.SetText(dialougeSt);
    }
}
```

Please tell how can I have an array or list in which I can do use my size variable and loop it until all dialogues are said.

I tried but mine doesn't work.
HELP!

Comment: This is, unfortunately, a very broad and vague question. What *exactly* is your immediate problem and question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What `size` has to do with your methods? Give us more details please.

Comment: `how can I have an array or list in which I can do use my size variable and loop it until all dialogues are said` You seem to be describing a `for` loop. That's _way_ out of scope; this can be answered by reading basic C# documentation. StackOverflow is not a brute force teaching service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dialogue system in itself is a very broad topic. However, I don't think you will be able to pull it off with just a List of strings. If you are talking about giving the player choices to choose from then you will need to create a few custom classes.

First, you will need a class to define your Character's Options. This will be a very simple class. It will contain the string response and an integer that will represent a destination node.

```
public class DialogueOption {

    public string Text;
    public int DestinationNodeID;
}
```

Next, you will need a DialogueNode class. Consider this what the NPC is telling the character and then it also contains a list of, you guessed it, Dialogue Options. The other thing it will have is a NodeID. This is an integer that gives us a place to send us to from our Options. It will look a little like this:

```
public class DialogueNode {

    public int NodeID = -1; //I use -1 as a way to exit a conversation.
    //NodeId should be a positive number

    public string Text;
    public List<DialogueOption> Options;
}
```

Finally, you will need to create your Dialogue class, which is the simplest of them all, just a list of DialogueNodes and looks something like this:

```
public class Dialogue {

    public List<DialogueNode> Nodes = new List<DialogueNode>();
}
```

You can have it where your character has just one dialogue script but, I did it differently where each character then had another class called DialogueList, which basically is a list of dialogues and it also contained the character's name that I could display and depending on the situation I could pick which dialogue I wanted my character to have with the player at the time.

```
public class DialogueList
{
    public string name;
    public List<Dialogue> dialogues = new List<Dialogue>();

}
```

This also has the added benefit of being easily converted to a Dictionary using the name as a key returning a list of dialogues if you wanted to set it up in that direction.

And somewhere else in your project you will need a DialogueManager class that will control everything. I typically make this a Singleton just so I can easily call it from anywhere. I won't show you all of it but I will show you the displaying part the rest is just setting the text and turning on and off objects.

```
public void RunDialogue(string name, Dialogue dia)
{
    nameText.text = name;

    StartCoroutine(run(dia));
}

IEnumerator run(Dialogue dia)
{
    DialoguePanel.SetActive(true);

    //start the convo
    int node_id = 0;

    //if the node is equal to -1 end the conversation
    while (node_id != -1 )
    {
        //display the current node
        DisplayNode(dia.Nodes[node_id]);

        //reset the selected option
        selected_option = -2;

        //wait here until a selection is made by button click
        while (selected_option == -2)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        }

        //get the new id since it has changed
        node_id = selected_option;

    }

    //the user exited the conversation
    EndDialogue(node_id);

}
```

My buttons basically just had this simple method attached to them in their OnClick event that I set under the DisplayNode method. Basically, I take my buttons and give them this method and their parameter is whatever their `DialogueOption.DestinationId` is

```
public void SetSelectedOption(int x)
{
    selected_option = x;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! You helped a lot!

Comment: @GamingForever if you start to get a lot of dialogues and content, you can save and convert your information to an XML format pretty easily. However, you can do it all in the editor too if that works for you haha

Comment: @GamingForever Remember that if this answer helped you so much, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm if you are asking for a Dialogue System it is very easy to create on Unity using UGUI.

1.) Create a canvas with a `plane` and a `text` I guess will do

```
*scale the plane ofcourse to your satisfaction and put it infront of the camera 
*and about the text you must put it infront of the plane like the plane is on the back
*and the text is infront of the plane.
```

2.) Now setup your heirarchy like this

```
Canvas
   Dialogue //Empty GameObject
      Plane
      Text
```

I'll make it pop out whenever you collides into an NPC something like that

```
[SerializeField] GameObject dialogueObject; //here drag the canvas
[SerializeField] GameObject text; //we will get its component for changing the text later on
void Start(){
   text = GetComponent<Text>().text = "Sample Dialogue";
   dialogueObject.setActive(false);
}

void OnCollisionEnter(collision collide){
    if(collide.gameObject.name == "NPC"){
        dialogue.setActive(true);
    }
}
```

Simple as that . I hope it helps